# mysql force use of multiple indexes in "where" clause having "or"

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let say I have table `clients` with `name1` and `name2` columns. Both columns have separate indexes. I run query

```
  select * from clients use index (`name1_index`,`name2_index`)
  where 
    name1='John'
  or
    name2='Doe'
```

In big table it's optimal to perform 2 queries separately and combine the results. But when I `explain` this one mysql8 (the one from oracle) tells me it's using where (and takes much more time than 2 separate queries)

I can imagine it's possible to rewrite this using 'union' which would likely work as expected but real live query is way more complicated than this example

So is there a way to force using multiple indexes?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I thied this with index hinting, explain show them as possible keys, anyway still using where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL should use both indexes automatically if they are worth using.

I did this experiment:

```
CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name1` (`name1`),
  KEY `name2` (`name2`)
)
```

I filled it with a few thousand rows of random data, and also a row for John Smith and a row for Jane Doe.

Then I did EXPLAIN for your query:

```
mysql> explain select * from clients where name1='John' or name2='Doe'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: clients
   partitions: NULL
         type: index_merge
possible_keys: name1,name2
          key: name1,name2
      key_len: 43,43
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using union(name1,name2); Using where
```

The `key` and `key_len` fields show that it's using both indexes.

Extra says `Using union(name1,name2)` which shows it's using the [Index Merge Union Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html). That is, it's doing a lookup of rows matching each index, then merging these sets of rows for the final result.

But in practice, I do experience that MySQL doesn't always use an index-merge when you think it should. I don't know of a way to persuade it to do so.

MySQL has a cost-based optimizer. It estimates the "cost" of using each index versus not using the index. If it estimates that it's cheaper to do a table-scan than to go to the extra work of using an index, it will skip the index. Its estimate is usually correct, but occasionally it isn't.

You can influence the cost-based optimizer using FORCE INDEX, which is a hint that a table-scan is infinitely costly, so MySQL should use the index if there's any way to do so. Of course, an index on another column of the table like `created_at` would be totally irrelevant to the conditions in your example query, so FORCE INDEX would still not use that index even if you tried to force it to.

There's a way to *disable* the index-merge feature, by removing that option from the [optimizer_switch](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_optimizer_switch) variable. But it is enabled by default.